# Why does const auto &p{nullptr} work while auto *p{nullptr} doesn't in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, auto, nullptr

This definition works:

```
const auto &b{nullptr};
```

while this fails:

```
auto *b{nullptr};
```

I have tried to compile this in Visual C++, GCC, and Clang. They all complain "cannot deduce type".

In the second case, shouldn't `b` be deduced to have some type like `std::nullptr_t`?

Comment: did you mean to use `auto b{nullptr};` ?

Comment: if you think the second `b`would have type `std::nullptr_t`, what type do you think the first `b` has?

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks `std::nullptr_t b;` is more readable?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's because you declare `b` to be a *pointer*, and initialize it to be a null pointer. But a null pointer to what type of data you don't say, so the compiler can't deduce the type.

If you want `b` to be a `std::nullptr_t` object, you should drop the asterisk:

```
auto b{nullptr};
```

Comment: Thanks! I have just realized that nullptr has type std::nullptr_t which is not a pointer.... It is strange but make sense in this case.

Comment: @felix It ceases to be strange when you take into account that `nullptr` is convertible to both all pointer types and also all member pointer types.

Answer (score 16):

`decltype(nullptr)` is `std::nullptr_t`.

so with

```
const auto &b{nullptr}; // auto is std::nullptr_t
// b is a reference to a temporary (with lifetime extension)
```

but `nullptr` is NOT a pointer (even if it is convertible to).

so `auto *b{nullptr};` is invalid.

You might use instead

```
auto b{nullptr}; // auto is std::nullptr_t
```

Answer (score 13):

`nullptr` is of type `std::nullptr_t`. As a `nullptr` does not point to anything, there is no corresponding pointee type for `std::nullptr_t` (you are not allowed to dereference a `nullptr`), hence

```
auto *b { nullptr};
```

requests a type that does not exist. If you want `b` to be of type `nullptr_t` simply write

```
auto b { nullptr};
```